# Snow Leopard: how can I monitor loading of specific extensions?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, kext, kernel-extension

I'm installing the [VoodooHDA](http://code.google.com/p/voodoohda/) extension in order for `Intel 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio 8086:293E` sound card to operate.

The sound card does not work but I have no idea how to debug the issue.

1. How can I check if the module was loaded properly?
2. How can I make sure that there were no conflicts?
3. How can I make sure that there were no dependencies issues with another module?

Using Mac OS X Snow Leopard (version 10.6) 64 bit.

## Update

I patched the original DVD in order for it to be installed on a PC,
I do not use any [Hackintosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSx86) build.
I boot using -v parameter for verbose but there is no output regarding the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kextstat(8)    - display status of loaded kernel extensions (kexts)
kextload(8)    - load kernel extensions (kexts) into the kernel
kextunload(8)  - terminate driver I/O Kit driver instances and unload kernel extensions (kexts)
kextutil(8)    - load, diagnose problems with, and generate symbols for kernel extensions (kexts)
```

I can manually load/unload the module using these utils and get error reports.

In general using kextutil alone to load the modules (kextutil .kext) will load the module and show dependencies and other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that you've got Mac OS on a 'Hackintosh', as Mac OS X audio works out of the box on regular Macs.  I would check with whichever 'distribution' you're running with to see how to boot the kernel in verbose mode, which would tell you if the module loaded properly.

Comment: I patched the original DVD of snow leopard and installed it.
verbose mode does not show any information regarding the module.